# Integrate $\frac{\lambda y^{2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(\frac{1}{2}+ \lambda x)y^{2}}$ with respect to $y$

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

$$F(x,y)= \frac{\lambda y^{2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(\frac{1}{2}+ \lambda x)y^{2}}$$

Please show that the function when integrated with respect to $y$ is 
$F_X(x)= \frac{\lambda}{(2\sqrt{2}(\frac{1}{2}+ \lambda x)^\frac{3}{2})}$ using $u =(\frac{1}{2}+ \lambda x)y^{2}$ and the gamma function.

Comment: Can you edit your question with [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: Not sure will give it a go

Comment: Try it. It will make you familiar with the use of $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @Bob I already edited the question to save time.  It's **really important** that you review my edits right away and tell me if I need to fix anything, before anyone starts working on the problem as stated.  For example, I wonder if there is a missing "$=$" sign after $F_{x}(x)$.

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot: I think it would be better to let him edit.

Comment: @user170039 Why do you think that? By the time he learns the appropriate syntax and edits his problem, people will have lost interest in checking the question out and helping him.  He should spend time learning the syntax before posting the next question, not during this one.

Comment: @mathishardnoitsnot thank you very much that edit is perfect. I will review your edit and attempt using that next time if I can.

Answer (score 0):

So, the two main passages are the change of variable and the gamma function. I'm supposing you want to integrate it between $0$ and $+\infty$.Therefore:

\begin{equation}
F_x(x) = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\lambda y^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x)y^2} dy= \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x)} (\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x) y^2 e^{-(\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x)y^2} dy =
\end{equation}

Let's change the variable by imposing $u=(\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x)y^2$ so that we have:

\begin{align}
& du= 2(\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x)y dy\\[5pt]
& y = \sqrt{\frac{u}{(\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x)}}
\end{align}

Applying the variable change leads to:

\begin{align}
Fx(x) &= \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x)} \int_0^{+\infty} u\,\, e^{-u} \frac{1}{2(\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x)\,y(u)} du \\[10pt]
&= \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x)} \int_0^{+\infty} u\,\, e^{-u}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x}}{2(\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x)\,\sqrt{u}} du \\[5pt]
&= \frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{2\pi} (\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x)^{3/2}} \int_0^{+\infty} u^{\frac{1}{2}}\,\, e^{-u} \,\,du
\end{align}

The latter integral is the gamma function of $\frac{3}{2}$ as the gamma function is defined as:

\begin{equation}
\Gamma(z) = \int_0^{+\infty} t^{z-1} e^{-t} dt
\end{equation}

Since that $\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})= \frac{\pi}{2}$ (the reason is not easy to prove, but you can retrieve those particular values from the wikipedia page) you have that:

\begin{equation}
Fx(x) = \frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{2\pi} (\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x)^{3/2}} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} = \frac{\lambda}{4\sqrt{2} (\frac{1}{2} + \lambda x)^{3/2}}
\end{equation}

I still have a $\frac{1}{2}$ difference with your solution and honestly at the moment I can't figure out exactly where the mistake is, but I hope it can be still a useful reply.

Comment: Could it be the fact that the integral over y from −∞ to ∞ of an integrand which is a function solely of y2 is twice the integral over y from 0 to ∞ of the same integrand (by a symmetry argument) ?

Comment: Absolutely, yes.